# How to GREP a substring of a filename for renaming files?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a lot of files that were named with `example1_partofEx1A_individualfile_name.fil`.

I have since organized the files into a directory structure so the path is `./example1/partofEx1A/example1_partofEx1A_individualfile_name.fil`.

I am trying to write a script that can take the unnecessary info out of the filename. I basically want to grep the 'individualfile' part so I can use a loop and mv.

I have no experience with scripting, just some with matlab. Using ubuntu or macOS. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to transform a filename into a corresponding directory name. Then I would create the directory if it doesn't exist yet with `mkdir -p` and then finally move the file into its dedicated directory using `mv`.

But I guess you should first read some information about scripting in bash. E.g. https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: @user3159253, `sed` itself should only be used when mandatory -- I'd strongly question any tutorial that advises reaching for it before the shell's built-in string manipulation tools, as described in [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100); using an external tool incurs startup costs that are avoided with internal approaches.

Comment: What exactly are the rules to identify the part of the name you are interested in? If you for instance have a file, say, `u_v_w_x_y_z.fil`, what part should be extracted? And: Do you **have** to use POSIX shell? String manipulation is much easier in zsh or bash.

Comment: @user1934428 I prefer bash. I am specifically interested in say  the x part, but its more like u_v_w_28_x_y_z.fil, u_v_w_29_a_y_z.fil, etc. So I want to extract everything but u_v_w and _y_z

Comment: You say to prefer bash, but by using the _shell_ tag, you express that you are interested in a POSIX shell solution. Please edit your question so that one can understand that this is bash related.

Comment: @user1934428 Apologies, I was referring to general shell scripting. Fixed with appropriate tags. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _general_ shell scripting.  People who want to write scripts which are supposed to run "nearly anywhere", often use POSIX shell for compatibility. Or do you mean: Any shell language is fine, as long as it solves your problem? Then I would write this explicitly in the question AND add tags for all common shells (bash, ksh, zsh).

Comment: @user1934428 I was meaning that I am so green that the differences between sh, bash, ksh, zsh are all just as foriegn. I appreciate all the help, and have begun focusing on bash. I found enough resources and starting points for scripts that the problem has been solved. Tags are updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for f in ./*/*/*; do
  [[ $f =~ ^[.]/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) ]] || continue
  dir1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  dir2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  filename=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

  [[ $filename = "${dir1}_${dir2}_"* ]] || continue
  new_name=${filename#"${dir1}_${dir2}_"}
  mv -- "$f" "${dir1}/${dir2}/$new_name"
done
```

---

Tested as follows:

```
testdir="$(mktemp -d)"
cd "$testdir" || exit
mkdir -p ./dirA/dirB
touch dirA/dirB/dirA_dirB_hello_world.txt
touch dirA/dirB/other_content_here.txt

for f in ./*/*/*; do
  [[ $f =~ ^[.]/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*) ]] || continue
  dir1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  dir2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  filename=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

  [[ $filename = "${dir1}_${dir2}_"* ]] || continue
  new_name=${filename#"${dir1}_${dir2}_"}
  mv -- "$f" "${dir1}/${dir2}/$new_name"
done
```

...whereupon the directory contains:

```
./dirA
./dirA/dirB
./dirA/dirB/hello_world.txt
./dirA/dirB/other_content_here.txt
```

Comment: This pretty much solved it. I had to rtm to figure out the regex details the double brackets, but I was able to piece together my own script off of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/rootdir || exit

for file in *.fil;do
    IFS=_ read dir1 dir2 individual <<<"$file"
    if [ "$individual" ] ;then
        test -d "$dir1/$dir2" || mkdir -p "$dir1/$dir2"
#       mv -v "$file" "$dir1/$dir2/$individual"
        mv -vt "$dir1/$dir2" "$file"
      fi
  done
```

As suggested by [Charles Duffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/105201191?noredirect=1), I've added `-p` flag to `mkdir` in order to prevent race condition.

Comment: I'd suggest a `|| exit` on the end of that `cd` command so the script can't run in the wrong directory if it fails. Also, better to just use `mkdir -p` instead of `test -d ... || mkdir ...`, as the former avoids race conditions present in the latter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If rootdir does contain a lot of file and script is run handly or via crontab, race condition won't ever be and having to fork, for all files, to `mkdir` could improve execution time.

Comment: If you're concerned about microoptimizing, `test -d "$dir1/$dir2" || mkdir -p "$dir1/$dir2"` -- only *one* fork in the directories-not-yet-created case rather than two. That said, as I read the question, the OP already created the directories and moved their files into them, and *only* still needs to rename the files.

Comment: @Xavier-Quinn: I commented an alternative `mv` command who will *rename* file while *moving* them.

Comment: This is a great starting point. The directory structure above the files is already in place. The other thing is that the files are not named specifically with one underscore. That is where I was hoping to search for strings that might include underscores such as 'May_Photos_Home_pic0001_camera_A.jpg and I want the file now to say pic0001.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the three parts (the first two to delete and the third to be kept) are always separated by underscores, this could be a possible solution:

```
for f in /path/to/rootdir/*; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed "s/\/.*_.*_/\//")"
    fi
done
```

where `/path/to/rootdir` is the root directory of your structure.

Comment: Without quotes, this is prone to some quite serious bugs. `mv -- "$f" "$(sed ... <<<"$f")"` avoids string-splitting and globbing values before passing them to `mv`.

Comment: (Also, starting a separate copy of `sed` per file found is just *slow*; you're going to eat as much time running copies of `sed` as you do with the actual `mv`s).

Comment: Absolutely agree about the first comment, but the performance issue doesn't seem too problematic in this exact situation. I'm updating the answer anyway, thank you.